# WYSIWYG Custom field Post Help text

Tags: wysiwyg, user-interface, user-experience

Is there a way to have custom field Post Help text HTML formatted? Not even new lines are recognised and it makes the help text very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is "no you can't configure that to allow HTML tags". If you need lots of Help text put most of that into the 'Body' on the Event Info and/or Event Register and/or Contribution pages - keeping the help text nice and short.

Comment: How would you hack it?

Comment: I would not hack it! :-)

Comment: Rephrasing it, how would I hack it? :)

Comment: I like short help text but formatted. HTML is not always the equivalent of long boring help texts.

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about a field on a public-facing profile, you can add a profile "field" of type "Formatting", which can be HTML-formatted.  See screenshot.

If you ARE committed to hacking this, I'd do so by inserting a jQuery script into an .extra.tpl file.

[image]

Comment: No I am talking about the Help text of any custom contact field. The help text is always unformatted and therefore hard to read for the user. I would like to introduce <ol><li> but the help text of a custom field does not accept this.